# Get some piece of string regex

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-group

I have the strings below and I just want to get the value of string: `AttributeReferenceID`. What I need to do?

I tried this `[A]ttributeReferenceID    (?<referenceID>\d+)` but can't success. The string that I want is at any part of the log, so the string could be at the first line, second or in the last line.

String to get:

```
AttributeReferenceID    123
AttributeReferenceID    456
AttributeReferenceID    789
```

String to discard:

```
ISCCAttributeReferenceID    091281 [09123na0]
ISCCAttributeReferenceID    123012 [i1208221]
ISCCAttributeReferenceID    091221 [0oas9019]
```

Comment: `[help-me]` Is the "good" `AttributeReferenceID` always at the start of the line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you regex flavor accepts positive lookbehinds, you can use the following

```
(?<=^AttributeReferenceID\s{4})(\d+)
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qusomV/2)**

The regex will look before the match if there is the specific string you're searching for followed by `4` spaces. If the length of the spaces may vary, then you'll have to find another solution. The following should normally work.

```
(?:^AttributeReferenceID\s+)(\d+)
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/YQcHv2/2)**

And take the first group.

Comment: Unfortunatelly the flavor of my regex is based on perl and **not accept this**. Other point, in your demo, the string `ISCCAttributeReferenceID` still returned in the results.

Comment: @RafaelMartins Are you sure, because I modified the answer and it shouldn't anymore since I use `^` now. See also the second answer, it may be working with your regex flavor.